# Meaning of notation in John Roe's Elliptic Operators book

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, heat-equation, spin-geometry

In the section about the asymptotic expansion for the heat kernel in the "Heat and wave equations" chapter of John Roe's book, he includes the following in one of this proposition:

Suppose that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ and that $S \to M$ is a Clifford bundle over $M$. Fix a point $q$ in $M$ and take a geodesic coordinate system ${x^i}$ with $q$ as the origin. Let $r^2=\sum (x^i)^2 = \sum g^{ij}x^{i}x^{j}$ so that $r$ is the geodesic distance from $q$, and define $h=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-r^2/4t}$. Then $\nabla h$ has the expression $-\frac{h}{2t}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ in this coordinate system.

What does $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ mean? I've only seen this notation for a vector when that vector is the image of the tangent vector to the coordinate curve $x^i$ in $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for some coordinate system $\{x^i\}$ on our manifold $M$. Is there some such coordinate neighborhood that's being implicitly used here? The notation is suggestive of polar coordinates. Should I first take polar coordinates on the tangent space at $q$ and then exponentiate to get this coordinate system?

Comment: Think of polar or spherical coordinates. What would $d/dr$ mean?